# Oracle query to search data based on values from an excel sheet

Tags: oracle11g

I want to write an oracle query to fetch data from table based on values(where clause) from an excel sheet. The excel sheet contains 3500+ values and i have to get data for all those 3500+ values from my database.

Comment: Are you stuck at how to import the data, how to write the query, or something else?

Comment: I would suggest you to use sql loader , load excel data into a temporary table and then write query.